# fade in multiple elements, then have them all fade out and be replaced

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm not sure if this is possible in jQuery, since this is bordering on just animation territory, but I figured I'd give it a shot.

I'd like to have multiple elements within a section fade in each onclick, and once the last element in that section appears, have the whole section fade out on click and be replaced with a new section.

Here's what I've tried, but the code isn't working:  http://jsfiddle.net/tuckyeah/xht9qbao/11/

**HTML**

```
    <div class="section-0">
    <div class="fadeIn">
        <p>I should show up.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="fadeIn">
        <p>Then me, then we should both disappear when we're clicked on.</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="section-1">
    <div class="fadeIn">
        <p>Then I should show up next.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="fadeIn">
        <p>Followed by me, then we should both fade out too when we're clicked.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**script**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.fadeIn').hide();
$(document).on('click', function () {
    $('.fadeIn:hidden:first').fadeIn('slow');
})
    .click();

if($('.section-0 fadeIn:last-child').is(':visible') ) {
$('.section-0').on('click', function() {
    $('.section-0').fadeOut('slow', function() {
           $('.section-1').delay('slow').fadeIn();
     });
 });
}
});
```

Thank you!

Comment: in your click handler, you could check if all `.fadeIn` elements of the only visible `.section-n` section were visible. If so, then click would hide everything in that section, increment n, and show the next section. You've almost got it...

Answer (score 0):

Replace your JS code with:

```
var fadeInNo = 0;
var fadeInSection = 0;

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.fadeIn').hide();
    $(document).on('click', function () {
        if(fadeInNo == 2) {
            $('.section-' + fadeInSection).fadeOut('slow');
            fadeInNo = 0;
            fadeInSection++;
        }
        else {
            $('.section-' + fadeInSection + ' .fadeIn:eq(' + fadeInNo + ')').fadeIn('slow');
            fadeInNo++;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it as i inderstood. Here it is –  [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xht9qbao/17/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.fadeIn:gt(0)').hide();
var $s1 = $('.section-1');
$('.section-0').on('click',function(){
    var $el = $(this);
    $el.find('>div:last-of-type').fadeIn();
    $el.on('click', function () {
        $el.fadeOut(300, function () {
            $s1.find('>div:first-of-type').fadeIn();
        });  
    });       
});
$s1.on('click',function(){
    var $el = $(this);
    $el.find('>div:last-of-type').fadeIn();
    $el.on('click', function () {
        $el.fadeOut(300);  
    });
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way:

```
$('.fadeIn').hide().click(function () {
    if ($(this).closest('.section').find('.fadeIn:visible').length < $(this).closest('.section').find('.fadeIn').length) {
        $(this).parent().find('.fadeIn:not(:visible):first').fadeIn('slow');
    } else {
        $(this).closest('.section').fadeOut('slow', function () {
            $(this).next().find('.fadeIn:first').fadeIn();
        })
    }
});
$('.fadeIn:hidden:first').fadeIn('slow');
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/5fsaxsk1/)**